# How to iterate through dict of dicts

Tags: python, json

I have the following json data

```
data_fixt_json = 
{"api": {"results": 402, 
"fixtures": [{
 "fixture_id": 127807,  
 "league_id": 297, 
"homeTeam": {
     "team_id": 2279, 
     "team_name": "Tigres UANL", 
     "logo":"url"},
"awayTeam": {
    "team_id": 2282,  
    "team_name": "Monterrey", 
    "logo": "url"}, 
"goalsHomeTeam": 1, 
"goalsAwayTeam": 0, 
"score": {
    "halftime": "1-0", 
    "fulltime": "1-0", 
    "extratime": null, 
    "penalty": null}}
```

I need to store in each key:value pairs in variables than use this variables to create objects in my database. I tried the following code

```
data_json = 
date_fixt_json["api"["fixtures"]
for item in data_json:
    fixture_id = item["fixture_id"]
    league_id = item["league_id"]
```

But when for loop go up to the dict "homeTeam" my script arrise error. How i can write code which will iterate through my json data and provide me opportunities to store values in variables

Comment: Can you post your full code, because date_fixt_json["api"["fixtures"] is invalid syntax and you don't show how you iterate through "homeTeam"

Comment: Updated. I iterate through homeTeam dict by the same code

Comment: @Naglyj.Spamer What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to iterate over the entries in a dict, you can do:

```
for fixture in date_fixt_json['api']['fixtures']:
    for key, value in fixture.items():
        print('key: {}, value: {}'.format(key, value))
```

Comment: Looks like `date_fixt_json['api']['fixtures']` is a list

Comment: Like i said in my question i need to store values in variables. I dont need to print them. How i can in your code save values of each keys to variables ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to think about here.

- **Do you know the number of items in the array?**

If you do, then consider simply using indexing to access the values - in this use case they are similar to variables.

```
data_array = ["api"]["fixtures"]

fixture_id1 = data_array[0]["fixture_id"]
```

- **Do you require variables?**

If you absolutely have to use variables, you can use the following concept, however I strongly recommend against doing this:

```
example = ['k', 'l', 'm', 'n']

for n, val in enumerate(example):
    globals()[f"var{n}"] = val

print(var2)

>>> m  #Output
```

Let me know if this helps - happy coding!